# ***missing separator. Stop. While eclipse trying to run OS/161

Tags: eclipse, makefile, os161

In line 13 .include "$(TOP)/mk/os161.config.mk"
I've installed OS161 tools and is trying to run OS161 over eclipse and was compiling the dependencies.

```
# Automatically generated by config; do not edit.
#

# Top of the kernel tree
KTOP=../..
# Top of the whole tree
TOP=$(KTOP)/..
# Debug vs. optimize
KDEBUG=-g
# Name of the kernel config file
CONFNAME=ASST0

.include "$(TOP)/mk/os161.config.mk"
.include "files.mk"
.include "$(TOP)/mk/os161.kernel.mk"
```

Comment: Please always include the exact error message (cut and paste) when asking questions.  For example, the make error you quote is not complete; the real error message would have a line number in it and that would tell you which line of the makefile is causing the problem.  Also you don't say what operating system you're using or what version of make.  However `.include` is not a valid command in GNU make; I believe BSD make and perhaps Solaris make might support it.

Answer (score 0):

Oops, sorry.
Turns out later OS161 comes with portable bmake, had to change the default make commend to bmake.